# Ember JS: How can a parent route/controller observe its child route/controller changing?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, parent-child

I'm making an Ember app to onboard users. The app has a progress bar that fills with an animation as you progress through the onboarding. I'm doing this by having the progress bar be a parent view for the individual steps changed inside it.

Now I need update the progress bar as the user works through the onboarding. Is there a way that my `ProgressBarRoute` / `ProgressBarController` can observe its child route/controller changing so that the parent view can handle updating the progress bar?

The routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('progressBar', function() {
        this.resource('pickApps'),
        this.resource('pickNetworks');
        this.resource('docs');
    });
});
```

The progress bar view, with an outlet for its child steps:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="progressBar">
  <section class="progress">
    {{!-- Progress bar here --}}
  </section>

  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd send an action from the child to the parent, it's always easier to communicate upstream than it is downstream (due to the fact that parents don't always have children).

Something along these lines:

```
App.ParentController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  actions:{
    newStep: function(step){

    }
  }
});


App.ChildController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  someMethod: function(){
    this.parentController.send('newStep', 7); // or whatever
  }
});
```

There is no need to duplicate the logic, you can set it up in a base route and have each resource extend that route.

```
App.BaseStepRoute = Em.Route.extend({

  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    var step = this.get('step'),
        progressController = this.controllerFor('progressBar');

    progressBar.send('newStep', step);
  }
});

App.PickAppsRoute = App.BaseStepRoute({
  step = 1,
  ...
});
```

Comment: Hm, that's kind of a shame b/c as I add more steps (I think I'll eventually have 6-7) I'll have to duplicate that code in all the child controllers. So far that does look like the easiest way, though

Comment: Are they different routes? N/m, I just looked at the question, looks like they are.

Comment: You should be able to implement most of it once, and just extend from a base class to avoid duplicating anything.

Comment: Ok that's what I'll do. Thanks @kingpin2k